# Tarball error while creating angular 2 application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an angular 2 sample application using angular-cli, I'm unable create the application and I'm getting the below error.

I'm using
Node: 6.10.0
npm: 3.10.10
angular-cli: 1.0.0-rc.2

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all  try :**

```
npm install -g tarball
```

**If its still not working** then issue is caused by anti-malware software :

So ,Remove any anti-malware software is installed on your machine and then try again.

> In most of the case : `ByteFence` is the application (remove it)

Comment: Yeah! This is working fine, Thanks for your answer @vivek Doshi